# Database server eating more than 100% from CPU

Tags: mysql, database-tuning

My database server eating more than 100% from  CPU

when i run mysqltuner its given following `recommendation`

```
]# sudo ./mysqltuner.pl

 >>  MySQLTuner 1.2.0 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

-------- General Statistics --------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.0.92-community
[!!] Switch to 64-bit OS - MySQL cannot currently use all of your RAM

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Archive -BDB +Federated +InnoDB -ISAM -NDBCluster
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 1G (Tables: 9347)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 477M (Tables: 1803)
[--] Data in MEMORY tables: 0B (Tables: 4)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 98

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 2d 8h 25m 8s (87M q [430.053 qps], 534K conn, TX: 2B, RX: 2B)
[--] Reads / Writes: 89% / 11%
[--] Total buffers: 670.0M global + 2.7M per thread (100 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 938.7M (30% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (1K/87M)
[!!] Highest connection usage: 100%  (101/100)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 8.0M/610.0M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 96.9% (10B cached / 331M reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 89.9% (73M cached / 81M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 148657
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (467 temp sorts / 560K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 11968
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 23% (334K on disk / 1M total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 86% (71K created / 534K connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 0% (80 open / 918K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 11% (117/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 96% (11M immediate / 11M locks)
[OK] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 477.2M/500.0M

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
    Reduce or eliminate persistent connections to reduce connection usage
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    Increase table_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
Variables to adjust:
    max_connections (> 100)
    wait_timeout (< 28800)
    interactive_timeout (< 28800)
    query_cache_size (> 96M)
    join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
    table_cache (> 80)


    Already my.cnf value is

[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 500M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size = 96M
query_cache_type = 1
table_cache = 128
thread_cache_size = 4
tmp_table_size = 96M
```

now what can i do in my.cnf
kindly help me
tks

Comment: The output is from MySQL - not SQL Server. Please tag correctly.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL eats more 100% because it can do so. Think, you have thyperthreading\multicore\multiprocessor server (or some combination).

On a dualcore+typerthreading system you have 4 virtual CPUs.
Every single fully loaded CPU makes "100% load" in the monitoring program such a **top**.
So some single program which can utilize multiple processors (mysql server do so) can eat up to 400% in that example.

More 100% load is not a bug by itself. It is just a symptom of something (good or bad). 
What is real problem, that forces you to look at CPU load?

">100% load" can be caused by high query rate or query complexity.

There are several ways to help server to execute queries faster

FIRST OF ALL
let's try what your script advised:

```
Variables to adjust:
    max_connections (> 100)
    wait_timeout (< 28800)
    interactive_timeout (< 28800)
    query_cache_size (> 96M)
    join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
    table_cache (> 80)
```

this can solve some problems with query and index caching subsystems. And also it allows the server eat more RAM and serve even more queries in parallel and elevate CPU load.

Also consider do:

- Examine queries to optimize table structure, rearrange queries. But I think, your indexes are rather good.
- Reduce query rate (joking ;-))